# frequent data update for ractive.js

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I was thinking on rewriting our legacy app which is using pure jQuery. It renders log data which it gets by websocket, it shows only last 100 records by removing old ones and appending new ones.

Because rendering speed matters, I've tried first to render random incoming data and Ractive's twice slower than our jQuery code. By benchmarks jQuery renders 1000 records in 15 seconds and Ractive's version in 30 seconds. ( our backend code pushes each event with 0.01 s delay )

Thus I wonder is there any tweak settings? The code I use is simple:

```js
        var LogApp = Ractive.extend({
          template: '#items',

          init: function() {
            var self = this;

            socket.bind("logs", function(data_raw) {
              var data = JSON.parse(data_raw);

              if (self.data.items.length > 100) {
                self.pop('items');
              }

              self.unshift('items', data);
            });

          }

        });

        var ractive = new LogApp({
          el: react,
          data: {
            items: []
          }
        });
```

```html
<script id='items' type='text/ractive'>
  {{#each items:i}} {{>item}} {{/each}}
</script>

<script id='item' type='text/ractive'>
  <tr>
    <td>{{id}}</td>
    <td>{{log_level}}</td>
    <td>{{log_message}}</td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: I messed around a bit and got it down to 18 seconds, but still slower than the update refresh rate (10 seconds). Going to use this to help drive some performance improvements.

Comment: Can you provide any code example how you could faster it to 18 seconds which is almost twice faster than my code?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay @nateless. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 2):

With Ractive `0.7`, performance is now better. It performs at ~11 seconds, with each item being about 10ms (See http://jsfiddle.net/aqe53ocm/).

You can also try using a `merge` instead of two operations, `pop` and `unshift`:

```
        var copy = self.get('items').slice();

        if (copy.length > 100) {
            copy.pop();
        }
        copy.unshift(data);

        self.merge('items', copy);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/56hfm4bt/.

For example and timings having the dev tools open will impact times because it's console.time logging each item, so try without.

For the curious, there are changes coming in `0.8` that will spead this up to ~`1ms` per item.

Comment: Hi martypdx, can you explain what you mean by "using edge..." ?